# Webapi - TryUpdateModel ou UpdateModel em um ApiController

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Tenho a seguinte situação, uma classe Pessoa, com propriedades Id, Nome, Nascimento, quero implementar uma pagina que possa atualizar somente o Nome da Pessoa. Minha implementação deve pegar uma pessoa pelo seu Id, e alterar somente o campo Nome.

Fiz a implementação abaixo em MVC, mas como eu poderia fazer o mesmo com WebApi, já que não tenho o TryUpdateModel ou UpdateModel. Implemento a funcionalidade com esta rotina para facilitar a generalização no futuro.

Código do Controller em MVC:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SetNome()
    {
        var sample = Pessoa.FindById(12);
        TryUpdateModel<Pessoa>(sample);
        return Json("sucesso");
    }
}

public class Pessoa
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime? Nascimento { get; set; }

    public static Pessoa FindById(int id)
    {
        return new Pessoa() { Id = 12, Nome = "Meu Nome", Nascimento = Convert.ToDateTime("1989-01-31") };
    }
}
```

Código da View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script>

        var app = angular.module("MainModule", []);

        var MainController = function ($scope, $http) {

            var url = 'http://localhost:47107/home/setnome';
            //var url = 'http://localhost:47107/api/values';

            $scope.pessoa = {};
            $scope.pessoa.nome = "xpto";

            $scope.enviar = function () {

                $http({
                    url: url,
                    method: "POST",
                    data: $scope.pessoa
                })
                .then(function (response) {
                    // success
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                },
                function (response) {
                    // failed
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                });
            }
        };

        app.controller("MainController", MainController);

    </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="MainModule">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
        <input id="pessoa.nome" ng-model="pessoa.nome" />
        {{pessoa.nome}}
        <button ng-click="enviar()">Enviar</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Código atual em WebApi:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public void Post([FromBody]Pessoa pessoa)
    {
        var sample = Pessoa.FindById(12);

        sample.Nome = pessoa.Nome;
    }
}
```

Queria ter que abstrair o preenchimento do campo Nome, assim como foi feito no MVC, com o UpdateModel, ele identifica quais os campos que foram enviados pela View e preenche somente eles, os outros ele mantém original. Com WebApi tenho que fazer isso manualmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ricardo, eu resolvo esse problema de uma forma diferente.

Inicialmente, minha Action ou Operation não recebem uma Entidade/Model, mas sim um DTO.

Recebendo um DTO, eu faria esse tratamento, que você deseja, em meu repositório.

Exemplo de um método de Repositório com esse recurso:

```
public void Alterar(TDTO DTO)
    {           
            var entidadeSemAlteracao = Context.Set<Compra>().Find(DTO.sID);
            DTO.ToEntity(entidadeSemAlteracao);
            Context.SaveChanges();            
    }
```

O **ToEntity** é uma extensão em meu DTO, chamando o AutoMapper.

```
public static TDestino ToEntity<TOrigem, TDestino>(this TOrigem DTO, TDestino entidadeDestino) where TDestino : EntidadeBase
    {
        var result = Mapper.Map(DTO, entidadeDestino);
        return result;
    }
```

Tudo acontece quando a extensão é chamada, que vai deixar as propriedades como **Modified** e o **SaveChanges()** vai alterar só essas propriedades.

O que acha?

Era isso que você queria?

Comment: Solução muito boa Henryle, apesar de eu estar tentando evitar usar AutoMapper neste projeto, pois é um overhead a mais de trabalho.

Answer (score 1):

Compartilhando conhecimento para quem passar pelo mesmo problema. Lembrando que o objetivo desta função não é validar a entidade e apenas preencher (complementar) uma entidade vinda do banco com os dados que vieram da view.

```
    protected virtual void UpdateModel<T>(T original, bool overrideForEmptyList = true)
    {
        var json = ControllerContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        UpdateModel<T>(json, original, overrideForEmptyList);
    }

    private void UpdateModel<T>(string json, T original, bool overrideForEmptyList = true)
    {
        //faz um comportamento similar ao do UpdateModel do Controller, onde sobreescreve as propriedades Enumarables,
        //caso no json a mesma esteja preenchida, se ela estiver vazia (não nula), sobreescreve também a não ser que,
        //o parametro overrideForEmptyList seja false
        var newValues = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);            
        foreach (var property in original.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var isEnumerable = property.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Any(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>));

            if (isEnumerable && property.PropertyType != typeof(string))
            {
                var propertyOriginalValue = property.GetValue(original, null);
                if (propertyOriginalValue != null)
                {
                    var propertyNewValue = property.GetValue(newValues, null);

                    if (propertyNewValue != null && (overrideForEmptyList || ((IEnumerable<object>)propertyNewValue).Any()))
                    {
                        property.SetValue(original, null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        JsonConvert.PopulateObject(json, original);
    }

    public void Post()
    {           
        var sample = Pessoa.FindById(12);
        UpdateModel(sample);            
    }
```

Comment: Aqui: `if (isEnumerable && property.PropertyType != typeof(string))` também compare com `Decimal` e `DateTime`. Essas classes também são consideradas não-primitivas.

Comment: Outra coisa: Isto aqui: `property.SetValue(original, null);` tem um desempenho péssimo. Cerca de 200ms por set de propriedade. Se usar extensivamente, recomendo usar a [FastMember](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FastMember/), que abaixa o tempo entre 40 e 50ms por propriedade.

Comment: Oi Cigano, o "if" eu quero verificar se a propriedade é um IEnumerable<>, como string é um IEnumarable e eu não quero ela na minha rotina, eu coloco ela na condição. não estou colocando-a na condição por ser um tipo primitivo.

Comment: Quando ao SetValue do property, realmente ele é lento, assim como a rotina por completa, pois utiliza reflection, mas somente a primeira execução, a segunda execução foi instantanea. Medi o tempo e a rotina completa roda em 129ms na primeira chamada, as chamadas seguintes é 0ms. Não conheço essa biblioteca FastMember, vou dar uma olhada. Obrigado pelas dicas.

Comment: Última coisa: `var newValues = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Pessoa>(json);`. Não seria `T` ao invés de `Pessoa`?

Comment: Isso mesmo, errei ali. Obrigado Cigano!